# DefaultBatchConfiguration extending in Spring Batch 5 not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

Just to implement a custom Batch Configuration for Spring Batch 5, following the official documentation on [Blog: Spring Batch 5 Milestone 6](https://spring.io/blog/2022/09/22/spring-batch-5-0-0-m6-and-4-3-7-are-out) and [JavaDoc Spring Batch 5 Milestone 8](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/5.0.0-M8/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/support/DefaultBatchConfiguration.html),
I wrote this code, using Spring Batch 5 via Spring Boot 3 RC1:

```
    @Configuration
    class MyBatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {        
        @Override
        protected DataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory getIncrementerFactory() {
            return new MyDataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory();
        }
    }
```

But I only get an error about my `MyBatchConfiguration#jobRepository` Bean, illegally overriding the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean#jobRepository` Bean. Which is weird, because `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` has no `jobRepository`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Error:

ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [my/package/MyBatchConfiguration.class]: @Bean definition illegally overridden by existing bean definition: Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodNames=null; destroyMethodNames=null

Edit: I built a demo project under https://github.com/JD-CSTx/SpringBatchBugJobRepo.

Comment: Can you please share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I added a demo project under https://github.com/JD-CSTx/SpringBatchBugJobRepo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you are using both `EnableBatchProcessing` and `DefaultBatchConfiguration`, which is not correct. From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/5.0.0-RC1/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig) of v5, you need to use either `EnableBatchProcessing` or `DefaultBatchConfiguration`, but not both:

```
    
@EnableBatchProcessing should not be used with DefaultBatchConfiguration.
You should either use the declarative way of configuring Spring Batch
through @EnableBatchProcessing, or use the programmatic way of extending
DefaultBatchConfiguration, but not both ways at the same time.
```

Spring Boot also has a note about this [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0.0-M5-Release-Notes#enablebatchprocessing-no-longer-required).

Answer (score 1):

I could fix the issue/your repo by:

- Moving `@EnableBatchProcessing` from:

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class ImportJobConfiguration {//...
  ```
- To:

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableBatchProcessing
  public class SpringBatchDemo extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {// ...
  ```

Reason are the details of [`BatchAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration.java).

**`DefaultBatchConfiguration` should** (currently/always) **be annotated `@EnableBatchProcessing`**.