# Testing Spring Batch 5 job junit5

Tags: spring-batch, junit5

I wrote a test code with spring batch 5.0 version, but an error about JobRepository occurs. I've searched a lot for documentation related to spring batch 5.0 version, but I haven't been able to solve it yet.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'jobRepository' defined in com.example.springbatchbasic.job.helloworld.HelloWorldJobConfig: @Bean definition illegally overridden by existing bean definition: Generic bean: class [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean];

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBatchTest
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SpringBatchTestConfig.class, HelloWorldJobConfig.class})
public class HelloWorldJobConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;

    @Test
    void success() throws Exception {
        // when
        JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();

        // then
        assertEquals(jobExecution.getExitStatus(), ExitStatus.COMPLETED);
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchTestConfig {
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class HelloWorldJobConfig extends DefaultBatchConfiguration{

    @Bean
    public Job helloWorldJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step helloWorldStep){
        return new JobBuilder("helloWorldJob", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()) 
                .start(helloWorldStep)
                .build();
    }

    @JobScope
    @Bean
    public Step helloWorldStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager){
        return new StepBuilder("helloWorldStep", jobRepository)
                .tasklet(helloWorldTasklet(), platformTransactionManager)
                .build();
    }

    @StepScope
    @Bean
    public Tasklet helloWorldTasklet(){
        return new Tasklet() {
            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Hello World Spring Batch");
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are mixing @EnableBatchProcessing processing and DefaultBatchConfiguration which are incompatible according to the answer given here [Extending DefaultBatchConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74154573/defaultbatchconfiguration-extending-in-spring-batch-5-not-working?rq=2) by Mahmoud Ben Hassine